# bad_weak_ptr while using class inheriting from boost::asio::io_context::service

Tags: c++, websocket, connection, boost-asio, boost-beast

I started to practice using boost asio & boost beast to develop my own basic server and connection class. Recently I've encountered bad_weak_ptr exception and I can't figure out how to manage the problem. Here is the code:

```
class server : public boost::asio::io_context::service
    {
        tcp::endpoint endpoint{ boost::asio::ip::address_v6::any(), 7654 };
        tcp::acceptor acceptor;
        boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand;
        std::vector<std::weak_ptr<tcp_connection_ui>> connections;
    public:
        static const boost::asio::execution_context::id id;

        explicit tcp_server_ui(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
            : boost::asio::io_context::service{ ioc }
            , acceptor{ ioc, endpoint }
            , strand{ ioc.get_executor() }
        {
        }

        void run()
        {
            boost::asio::post(strand, [this] {start_accept(); });
        }

        void start_accept()
        {
            tcp::socket socket{ acceptor.get_io_context() };
            tcp_connection_ui::pointer new_connection =
                tcp_connection_ui::create(std::move(socket));

            connections.push_back(new_connection);

            acceptor.async_accept(new_connection->web_socket().next_layer(),
                boost::asio::bind_executor(strand, std::bind(
                    &tcp_server_ui::handle_accept,
                    this, new_connection, std::placeholders::_1)));
        }

        void handle_accept(tcp_connection_ui::pointer new_connection,
            boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
            if (!ec) {
                new_connection->run();
            }

            start_accept();
        }

        void broadcast(std::string&& msg)
        {
            std::cout << '+' << std::endl;
            if (connections.empty())
                return;

            for (auto const & x : connections)
                x.lock()->enqueue_message(std::move(msg));
        }
    };
```

And there is the place where the code stops running:

```
class tcp_connection_ui : std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection_ui>
    {
    public:
        using pointer = std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection_ui>;

        static pointer create(tcp::socket socket)
        {
            return std::make_shared<tcp_connection_ui>(tcp_connection_ui{ std::move(socket) });
        }

        void run()
        {
            ws.async_accept(boost::asio::bind_executor(strand, std::bind(
                &tcp_connection_ui::on_accept, shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1)));
        } .../};
```

If the client tries to connect the value shared_from_this in server::handle_accept is equal to _Wptr = empty. I think i have some troubles with understanding io_context::service and/or shared_from_this feature. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you deriving from `service`? That looks wrong...a service is only needed in the most rare circumstances, implementing a typical server is not one of them.

Comment: This line looks like it has problems: `x.lock()>enqueue_message(std::move(msg));` You aren't checking the return value of `lock`. And you are transferring ownership of the message (because of move). What happens if the loops runs more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class must be inherited publicly:

```
class tcp_connection_ui : public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection_ui>
```

Otherwise, `make_shared` or `shared_ptr` will not notice it and subsequently fail to initialize the "hidden" weak_ptr

Comment: Oh boy... I am so distracted sometimes. Thank you very much. A little help but saved me so much time!